# Grep not working for one file several times

Tags: bash, grep

I need to search for open and close html tags and print how many have been found. But seem to be second use one file is not working. Second block shows me every time 0 tags. If i move second block above first then it show me right number of tags, but the block that is now on second place does show 0 tags.

```
./s.sh <my.html


TAG=$(grep -oP "<([^>\/]+)>" $1 | wc -l)
echo "<TAG> -" $TAG

CTAG=$(grep -oP "</([^>\/]+)>" $1 | wc -l)
echo "</TAG> -" $CTAG
```

I'm getting this output:

```
<TAG> - 13
</TAG> - 0
```

But should get something like this:

```
<TAG> - 13
</TAG> - 11
```

Input example:

```
<HTML>
    <P>Список сотрудников
    <TABLE BORDER=0>
        <TR><TH>ФИО</TH><TH>Дата</TH></TR>
        <TR><TD>Иванов И.И.</TD><TD>10.12.2019</TD></TR>
        <TR><TD>Сидоров А.В.</TD><TD>11.11.1977</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    <P>Всего: 2 чел.
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please, provide sample input and expected output. And it seems you try to parse html or xml with grep, that is not the right tool here

Comment: Thanks for editing, but still missing sample input

Comment: Looks like you just need to quote `$1`, use `"$1"`

Comment: `</([^>\/]+)>"` why is `\/` included in `[...]` when it also begins the expression `</`? (*note:* parsing html with shell tools is not recommended)

Comment: No, this won't work..

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/qcqsuI)

Comment: Yeah, it works, but i need to pass file)

Answer (score 0):

No need to escape the slash in the pattern, and you can omit the capturing group and the `-P` option:

```
$ TAG=$(grep -o "<[^>/]*>" "$1" | wc -l)
$ echo "<TAG>: " $TAG
<TAG>: 13

$ CTAG=$(grep -o "</[^/>]*>" "$1" | wc -l)
$ echo "</TAG>: " $CTAG
</TAG>: 11
```